# Can't figure out how to clear the text of a select box using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, combobox

So if it makes a difference, I am using JQuery UI. I have a selectbox which is turned into an autocomplete, but I think that I **should** be able to clear it just like any old select box...

I have tried everything that I have read online:

```
$("#edit_ts_form_projects").val("0");
$("#edit_ts_form_projects").val(" ");
$("#edit_ts_form_projects nth-option(0).(selected, "selected");//or something like this, cant remember the synax
```

All of those with a blank first item in the select, with just a space:

```
<option value=" "> </option>
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="..">..</option>
```

But no matter what, but selectbox will still have stuff in it (I want the dropdown part to stay intact, I just want to clear the textbox.

Any ideas? Could it be because I am using JQuery UI that this is happening?

Here is the link to the jquery UI control I am using btw:

[Jquery UI Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('#combobox').next().find('input').val('');
```

Where `#combobox` is the ID of the drop down in your original code.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/vakKq/1/